# How do you send File paths from html file inputs via Ajax?

Tags: ajax

How do you send File paths from html file inputs via Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to get it in chrome but it returned unexpected value it may be for security reasons

---

```
//i have an input of file type with name image_file
//<input type=​"file" name=​"image_file"/>​
var path = $('input[type=file][name=image_file]').val();
alert(path);
/*
i got "C:\fakepath\wattan-company-view.gif"
but it is in E:\..., but IE i don't know its behavior especially its earlier versions
*/
```

what i want to know is what will you need the path for?????
if you want to upload with ajax [iframe post form jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iframe-post-form) its very easy to use